# Angularjs v1 : Is it possible to create a data-custom-directive atrribute?

Tags: angularjs, directive, custom-attributes

All is in the question :

I understood I have to declare the string with two custom letters than the uppercase word giving sense to the directive for example

```
djLoad
```

in the directive declaration which becomes

```
dj-load
```

in the view.

How about declaring

```
 dataDjLoad
```

which would become

```
data-dj-load
```

in the view ?

Comment: `data-` is an standard for old browsers for new ones you don't need it, but yes you can do it.

Comment: it is just I am coding with NetBeans you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` prefix is stripped in the directive and attribute names by angular, so you should not use it. See "Normalization" section in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

The idea however is correct, directive declared as `myDirectiveName` (camelCase) should be used as `my-directive-name` or `my:directive:name` or `my_directive_name` in html.

If you still want to use the `data` prefix in your directive's name (e.g. `dataDjLoad`) - you should use it this way: `<div data-data-dj-load></div>`.

Here the [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rs9xvcfo/).

Comment: As you say should, I understand that it does not ?

Comment: So I can declare djLoad and use data-dj-load ? Because it tested it with no success ...

Comment: I am going to try it again then !

Comment: Great, it works indeed. I don't have have the knowledge yet to build my own framework !

Comment: @Mantisse, added example to the answer.

Comment: Just to show off, I added a cool functionnality to your code : 
https://jsfiddle.net/rs9xvcfo/1/

Comment: @Mantisse, did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes, indeed. By the way, angular responsiveness on load of big json data is impressive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115566/discussion-between-mantisse-and-alec-kravets).